# Error with UserPasswordCredential after enabling MFA

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, policy, azureportal, multi-factor-authentication

I am stuck at this issue while sending request for Azure Active Directory authentication from ASP.NET, using `UserPasswordCredential`, I get this error :

```
{
    "AADSTS50076: Due to a configuration change made by your administrator, or because you moved to a new location, you must use multi-factor authentication to access '00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'
```

Note : MFA is enabled.

Does any one know why this issue occur ? how to ignore MFA authentication while authenticate from API side.

Is there any policy to handle MFA authentication?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for [UsernamePasswordCredential Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.usernamepasswordcredential) clearly states this will not work:

> Enables authentication to Azure Active Directory using a user's username and password. If the user has MFA enabled this credential will fail to get a token throwing an `AuthenticationFailedException`. Also, this credential requires a high degree of trust and is not recommended outside of prototyping when more secure credentials can be used.

For an alternative solution, please see the documentation on [Managed identities for Azure resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview).

Comment: Can we do any settings to control MFA authentication in azure active directory while using UsernamePasswordCredential Class?

Comment: No, you cannot. For different authentication options please check out Managed Identities (link in answer) or Service Principal.

Comment: When i try with one Active Directory it is working with MFA.It is not working with Another. How to ignore MFA policy any idea about it? Any Conditional policy there?